# Turning off auto-renewing subscriptings on an iOS device in sandbox

Tags: ios, sandbox, auto-renewing

I have set up and tested In-App purchases successfully in sandbox environment. But I have a problem:

- In actual In-App purchases, I can turn off auto-renewing subscriptings on an iOS device by following this link http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4098?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US
- I wonder how I can do the same thing in sandbox environment. I thought we have to sign in App Store to turn off auto-renewing subscriptings, but Test User Account can not sign in App Store. So I think we can not turn off auto-renewing subscriptings in sandbox environment.
- If so, I also need a simple explanation why we can not.
- Thanks for reading and any help or direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. That was my experience as well: that test users can't access the settings page to manage subscriptions in their phone. I think Apple just didn't bother programming this knowing that sandbox subscriptions will just cancel after five repetitions anyway. That automatic cancellation is probably your way to test the scenario where a user cancelled through the App Store.

Comment: where are the auto-renewing subscriptings? i want to increase period of auto renewing subscriptions.

Comment: @AdeelIshaq Do you mean how do you edit them? Go to iTunes Connect > My Apps > In-App Purchases. From there you can edit your In-App Purchases by adding a duration or you can select Create New > Auto-Renewable Subscriptions > Add Duration, and go from there.

Comment: Andrew thank you so much for comment.i founded the auto-renewable subscriptions. But i am not getting products list in my game using sandbox user.while 2 weeks ago i am getting products list using sandbox user. what the hell is going on? i am strinking my head with wall.

Comment: Sorry @AdeelIshaq. I wish I could help you. IAP's can be complex sometimes.